# Google Cloud Firestore Triggers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How to add a new attribute for a newly created document by cloud function that was triggered by onCreate() cloud firestore trigger.
Does one can use same approach to upadate a document in client side as well as to server side ie in Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions#writing_data), you can use `event.data.ref` to perform operations:

```
exports.addUserProperty = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}')
  .onCreate(event => {
    // Get an object representing the document
    // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
    var data = event.data.data();

    // add a new property to the user object, write it to Firestore
    return event.data.ref.update({
      "born": "Poland"
    });
});
```

Comment: I opted for autogenerated Ids for documents.Then how can I add the path for specific document, because I don't know the document id

Comment: This is what the wildcard: `{wildcardId}` is for. It will capture all changes at that location.